# How to handle large matrix in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I would like to know how to deal with large matrix in Dymola.  I have an Modelica code that needs to read the values from a large txt file, and store it into matrix. The following is an example code that shows a 1000x1000 matrix.  I want Modelica to read the value from a txt file that stores the values for w2 (TXT file (~13 MB): [**THE LINK**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/etly5qb76gf4m4i/data.txt?dl=0)). The txt file already has the matrix format in Modelica language.  However, there are too many elements, and I cannot just manually copy the values to Dymola.  If I do that, Dymola will stop responding.

```
model Unnamed
  Real[1000, 1000] w2;
end Unnamed;
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57428822/compile-large-array-in-dymola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [ReadRealMatrixFromFile](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/Modelica.Utilities.Examples.ReadRealMatrixFromFile.html) example for some inspiration. You will need to have the file in a supported format, which your own text format is not. In that case, you could write your own parser or convert the file to the MAT files that MSL knows how to read.

Comment: Unfortunately, the ReadRealMatrixFromFile example mentioned above does not address or solve the problem posed by the OP. Rather, it suffers from the same problem... The actual problem is that Dymola will generate a line of C code for each element of a matrix. Therefore, a 1000x1000 matrix will generate 1000000 lines of C code. This is managed by separating the dsmodel.c file into multiple dsmodelext*.c files. Depending on the C compiler, this can result in unacceptably long compile times (i.e. a compile-time > 1000x the run-time). I am unaware of a workaround at this time.

Comment: Use the annotation `__Dymola_HideArray=true`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/57461028/8725275.

Answer (score 4):

You could also have a look at the [`ExternData` library](http://impact.github.io/#/library/851a8c7871faba5b2a21251237f8e36e4f45e355) which supports a couple of more file formats.